# How to hidden Expand after clicking on the content? XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, expand

Need some help, is anyone know how to make it so that when you click on the contents of Expand - does it hidden?

```
        <Expander Header="First Expand">
            <ListBox>
                <ListBox.Items>
                    <CheckBox Content="First"/>
                    <CheckBox Content="Second"/>                                    
                    <CheckBox Content="Third"/>
                </ListBox.Items>
            </ListBox>
        </Expander>
```

Is it possible to use bindings?

Comment: or trigers, or something clear xaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use ToggleButton, and rewrite template (like Expander but Name = Header)

```
   <ToggleButton Style="{DynamicResource NewToggle}" 
                 Name="First Toggle" Click="Toggle_click">
        <ListBox>
            <ListBox.Items>
                <CheckBox Content="First"/>
                <CheckBox Content="Second"/>                                    
                <CheckBox Content="Third"/>
            </ListBox.Items>
        </ListBox>
    </ToggleButton>
```

Then use codebehind:

```
private void Toggle_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource.GetType().Name == "CheckBox") 
    { 
        var myCheck= (CheckBox)e.OriginalSource;
        var MyList = (ListBox)myCheck.Parent;
        var myToogle = (ToggleButton)MyList.Parent;
        myToogle.IsChecked = false;
    }
    return;
}
```

I think it's not a best idea

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example I wrote using bindings. If you "check" the 3rd checkbox, the Expander closes.  Note that the Expander doesn't close if you uncheck it (this is by my design only, your needs might be different).

```
        <Expander x:Name="firstExpand" Header="First Expand" IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded}">
            <ListBox>
                <ListBox.Items>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="firstCheckbox" Content="First" IsChecked="{Binding FirstChecked}"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="secondCheckbox" Content="Second"  IsChecked="{Binding SecondChecked}"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="thirdCheckbox" Content="Third"  IsChecked="{Binding ThirdChecked}"/>
                </ListBox.Items>
            </ListBox>
        </Expander>
```

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool firstChecked;
        private bool secondChecked;
        private bool thirdChecked;
        private bool isExpanded;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            this.PropertyChanged += MainWindow_PropertyChanged;
            this.IsExpanded = true;
        }

        private void MainWindow_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // If the third item was checked...close the expansion
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ThirdChecked) && ThirdChecked)
            {
                this.IsExpanded = false;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public bool FirstChecked { get => this.firstChecked; set { this.firstChecked = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(FirstChecked))); } }
        public bool SecondChecked { get => this.secondChecked; set { this.secondChecked = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SecondChecked))); } }
        public bool ThirdChecked { get => this.thirdChecked; set { this.thirdChecked = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ThirdChecked))); } }
        public bool IsExpanded { get => this.isExpanded; set { this.isExpanded = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsExpanded))); } }
    }
```

Comment: i mean property bindings) Like clear xaml, w/o code behind.Thank you for answer, but.. It's not look "elegant". Also, you can use "Click" (not "IsChecked")

Comment: Oh, "this is by my design only" ok, ty